Typesript: Search next word in a string after index
I have a string, let say
let myText = `The ball
    is in the garden`;

and I want a method that take that string and an index i (let it be 9) and returns the next word after i (in this case is)
Something like
nextWord(myText, 9) -> is

How would I write such a method in typescript ?
Thank you in advance

Not sure I understand why you are focusing on Typescript. Are the typings your main question because other than the typings you would write such a method in Typescript in the exact same way you'd write it in JavaScript.

Use String.indexOf()  to find the next word separator (for instance a whitespace) after your desired index. Then use String.slice() to get the substring between those two indexes. Be aware of border cases (for instance, what happens if no separator is found, because it's already the last word in the sentence)

That should do.


function nextWord(text, index) {
    const slicedText = text.slice(index);
    const match = slicedText.match(/\s+(\w+)/);
    return match ? match[1] : '';
}

let myText = `The ball
    is in the garden`;
console.log(nextWord(myText, 9));  // Output: "is"



